# What will happen to my body if I do not sleep at all?

Tags: sleep-deprivation

What happens if I try to stay awake for as long as physically possible?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. This question seems very broad, as many things could happen when you don't sleep at all. I'm afraid that there are just too many other factors that you may fail to recognize are important and without those, we can't accurately say what would happen. If you could add in more details, this question could possibly be reopened. Thanks :)